# Magento 2: How to get controller, module, action and router name?

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, router, action

**Magento 2**: How to get controller, module, action and router name?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the below code in the controller class to get the controller, module, action and route name:

```
<?php
    namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $moduleName = $this->request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $this->request->getControllerName();
        $action     = $this->request->getActionName();
        $route      = $this->request->getRouteName();

        echo $moduleName."<br/>";
        echo $controller."<br/>";
        echo $action."<br/>";
        echo $route."<br/>";

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Manashvi,can we get controller and action name from referralUrl?

Answer (score 20):

to get `phtml` file or `controller` use below

```
echo $controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
echo $actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
echo $routeName = $this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
echo $moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
```

Comment: How can I get home page controller action to set an observer ?

Comment: if you test this code it will output for homepage  `controller:index,action:index,route:cms,module:cms` hope this will help.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, can we get controller and action name from the referral url?  $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();

Answer (score 9):

You can also do :

`$this->_requestInterface->getFullActionName()`

To get the full action name

Answer (score 3):

**Try not to use Objectmanager. It is just for fast implementation**

> If the url is http://localhost/mage242/customer/account/login

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
echo $request->getRouteName() . '<br />';           //customer
echo $request->getModuleName() . '<br />';          //customer
echo $request->getControllerName() . '<br />';      //account
echo $request->getActionName() . '<br />';          //login
echo $request->getFullActionName() . '<br />';      //customer_account_login
echo $request->getControllerModule() . '<br />';    //Magento_Customer
```

*Vote this answer up if it helps.*

Answer (score 1):

You can get these information from request object.

> Example

In your `controller` class:

```
$routeName        = $this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$moduleName       = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$controllerName   = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName       = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

I hope this will help.