# Get only the page path of the URL

Tags: magento2, url

I need to get the path of the current page like - /customer/account/ NOT http://magento.dev/customer/account/index/

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite URL?

Comment: @syahidahhumairoh I tried this - `$this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);`

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104638/69

Answer (score 4):

Within a block, you should be able to use...

```
<?php echo $block->getRequest()->getRequestUri() ?>
```

...to return just the path portion of the full current page URL.