# Redirect to login page with exception

Tags: magento-1, login, redirect

I using the following code to redirect all visitors to the login page. Everything is working fine with the exception of the **Forgotten Password link**... how would be make an exception for that `/customer/account/forgotpassword/`

```
$redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login/');
$current_url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

    if ((!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) && ($current_url != $redirect_url)) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url);
    }
```

Comment: On the top of the page you can check the conditiona that if controller action name is not forgotpassword. This is the simplest way I can suggest.

Comment: @AjayGehlod would it be something like this `$this->getRequest()->getControllerName() = 'forgotpassword'`

Comment: forgotpassword is your action name not a controller name. 
Get an idea from here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104639/73952